# How to pass the sesssion value as hidden value in struts2?

Tags: struts2

I want to pass a session value as a hidden form value to an action class.

I have seen several examples but nothing worked for me; I get a `null` in the action.

**Update.jsp:**

```
<s:hidden name="name"  value="%{#session.sname}" />
<s:property value="#session.sname"></s:property>//works fine and printing username
```

User name is stored in session. I want to send this name to action class but I am unable to send.

**UpdateAction.java:**

```
public class UpdateAction extends ActionSupport {

    String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public string execute() {
       System.out.println("Username"+name);//getting null value
    }

}
```

Comment: Post your form where from you submit that hidden value and action configuration.

Comment: Why do you need to do that if you can implement `SessionAware` and get the value from session.

Comment: yes @RomanC is right why do you need to pass session value like this?

Comment: you may forgot to add `<s:form>` if not check HTML, r u getting value in html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try:

```
<s:hidden value="%{#session['sname']}" name="aName"></s:hidden>
```